# How to right align a search bar

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

how to right align the search bar ? I've tried everything nothing seems to work. I want the 'Transaction' title on the left of the card and search bar on the right of the card

this is my code

```
    export default function ContactsCard(Rows) {
  return (
    <Card sx={{ minWidth: 900, minHeight: 1, }}>
      <CardContent>
        <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center"  gap={1}>
          <RuleIcon sx={{ color: "text.secondary" }} />
          <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }} textAlign='start' color="text.secondary" gutterBottom>
            Transactions
          </Typography>
          <SearchBar rows={rows} />
          </Stack>
        <DataGridHelper title='Contact' rows={Rows} columns={columns} />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

this how my table looks like now
[image: a]

Comment: You are missing `justifyContent` in `Stack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a wrapper to the icon and typography with `display="flex" flexDirection="column"`  and `justifyContent="space-between"` in `Stack`

```
export default function ContactsCard(Rows) {
              return (
                <Card sx={{ minWidth: 900, minHeight: 1, }}>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" justifyContent="space-between" gap={1}>
                     <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
                      <RuleIcon sx={{ color: "text.secondary" }} />
                      <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }} textAlign='start' color="text.secondary" gutterBottom>
                        Transactions
                      </Typography>
                     </Box>
                      <SearchBar rows={rows} />
                      </Stack>
                    <DataGridHelper title='Contact' rows={Rows} columns={columns} />
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              );
            }
```